# Convert Query Builder query to Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, orm, laravel-5

I want to convert my current **query** to `ORM`. But, I cant understand clearly how to join.

**My current query:**

```
        $result=DB::table('tests')
            ->join('tests_matchs', 'tests_matchs.matched_tests_id', '=', 'tests.id')
            ->where('tests_matchs.user_id', '=', $UserId)
            ->where('tests_matchs.passed', '=', 'true')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relationship is set correctly this should work:

```
$result = Test::with('tests_matchs' => function($query) user ($UserId){ 
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $UserId)
        ->where('passed', '=', 'true');
})->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pawel Bieszczad you forgot that with takes array as argument, so the correct query would be

```
$result = Test::with(['tests_matchs' => function($query) uses ($UserId){ 
           $query->where('user_id', '=', $UserId)
                 ->where('passed', '=', 'true');
}])->get()
```